# Add constraint to table postgresql based on other tables

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have these three tables in postgres database:

```
create table staff ( 
e_id int primary key,
first_name text,
last_name text,
job text,
branch_name text);

create table temp_staff ( 
t_id int primary key,
t_first_name text,
t_last_name text,
t_job text );

create table replacements( 
e_id int ,
t_id int,
from_date date,
until_date date,
primary key(e_id, t_id, from_date) );
```

Now I want to add a constraint to the `replacements` table so you can insert a replacement with e_id and t_id only if e_id exists in the staff table and t_id exists in the temp_staff table.
I tried this:

```
alter table replacements
add constraint check_existence
check(exists (select 1 from staff where e_id = e_id) and exists (select 1 from temp_staff where t_id = t_id));
```

And got the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot use subquery in check constraint
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're looking for the foreign keys, not check constraints -- the latter can only reference columns in the same row.

Comment: `e_id int not null references staff(e_id), t_id int not null references temp_staff(t_id)`